# ListBox SelectedItem not working

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm

I'm trying to load a list of objects as grids with several data and I've selected ListBox for it as you can see here:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding Person, Mode=TwoWay}" >
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
     </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
         <Grid>
             <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="20"></ColumnDefinition>
             </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
             <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding name}" Grid.Column="0" TextAlignment="Right"></TextBlock>
             <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding age}"></TextBox>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text="yo" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
             <TextBox Grid.Column="3" Margin="5,0,0,0" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Text="{Binding baremo}"></TextBox>
             <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" Text="€" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0"></TextBlock>
         </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

When I load data into People ObservableCollection everything goes right and it is shown perfectly.

**The first time I select a Person, it works** and it sets the property value in the VM.

The problem comes **the second time** I select a different "Person". The property **doesn't change** and... **every time I select a different one, it takes a little longer** (after 10 ó 20 it is MUCH LONGER).

Here is my ViewModel code:

```
#region People
        public const string PeoplePropertyName = "People";

        private ObservableCollection<Player> _People;

        public ObservableCollection<Player> People
        {
            get
            {
                return _People;
            }

            set
            {
                _People = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(People);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Person
        public const string PersonPropertyName = "Person";

        private Player _Person;

        public Player Person
        {
            get
            {
                return _Person;
            }

            set
            {
                _Person = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(PersonPropertyName);
            }
        }
        #endregion
```

And I'm loading the People list like this:

```
void LoadPeople(GetPlayersEventArgs e)
{
     if (this.People == null) this.People = new ObservableCollection<Player>();

        foreach (Player Person in e.Result)
        {
            Player newPerson = new Player();
            ...
            this.People.Add(newPerson);
        }

        this.SetUnBusy();
}
```

Am I missing anything?? Thanks in advance.

After @Ryan question I've seen everytime I try to select another value, I get a lot of:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
>   occurred in Solution

Comment: How is `LoadPeople` called? What causes it to be called?

Comment: It's called when I press a button in the view (a command that calls a service that returns a list of objects).

Comment: why  Mode=TwoWay for itemsoruce property for listbox..try removing this

Comment: Oh I added this to see if this could affect... it didn't work anyway :-(

Comment: Do you get anything of relevance in your Output window?

Comment: I'm getting a lot of "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Solution"

Comment: @zapico I'd recommend turning on the feature that will break when a CLR exception is thrown. If you're using Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, go to Debug -> Exceptions (or Ctrl-E,D by default) and under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" make sure "Thrown" is checked on. Then re-run your solution and see if anything breaks.

Comment: Thanks Ryan!!! It was because of a problem inside my Person object!!! Please post this comment as an answer so I can choose it as the correct one ;-). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend turning on the feature that will break when a CLR exception is thrown. If you're using Visual Studio 2010 or 2012, go to Debug -> Exceptions (or Ctrl-E,D by default) and under "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" make sure "Thrown" is checked on. Then re-run your solution and see if anything breaks.

Then you'll see the problem in your Person object ;)

Answer (score 2):

From what you've shared the implementation of the `Person` property is good. There are a few things I would recommend.

As vinod8812 suggests, change the binding mode to `OneWay`, or remove it as `OneWay` is the default:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding People}" SelectedItem="{Binding Person, Mode=TwoWay}" >
```

Change the sequence of populating the `ObservableCollection<Player>` in your ViewModel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly ObservableCollection<Player>();

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _People = new ObservableCollection<Player>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Player> People
    {
        get
        {
            return _People;
        }
    }
    /* rest of class */
}
```

Finally, clear out the `_People` collection before populating it. Otherwise you may just be adding duplicates:

```
void LoadPeople(GetPlayersEventArgs e)
{
    _People.Clear();

    foreach (Player Person in e.Result)
    {
        Player newPerson = new Player();
        ...
        this.People.Add(newPerson);
    }

    this.SetUnBusy();
}
```

Is there anything that you know is bound to the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event on your `ViewModel`? It is not clear from the code you have shared exactly what could be causing the app to slow down.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "twoway" mode was just a try to see if it was been "reloaded" and it has been deleted already. I think that there's nothing bounded to the propertychanged event but the strange thing is: it increases every time I select a different one. And the strangest. The first time I select an item, the binded property is set, but after that it doesn't change...